# Sortable function in jquery not executing append on stop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've a certain div tags dynamically generated with jquery from a ul element. I've added a sortable function to these div, I position change to be  dynamic.

Following is my div elements:

```
<div class="form-body ui-sortable" id="nitspopupmenu">
  <div class="form-group ui-sortable-handle">
   <div class="pagesmenu selected"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Home
     </span>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="form-group ui-sortable-handle">
   <div class="pagesmenu selected"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> About Us
    </span>
   </div>
 </div>
 ....
```

Ul elements are:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nitsmenu" data-nitspagelabel="1">
  <li class="scroll active" data-menusort="1"><a href="#navigation">Home</a></li>
  <li class="scroll" data-menusort="2"><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
....
```

I'm trying to get the index value of the sortable element and trying to replace with the data tag of the li elements so that we can see the change dynamically so I've done following code:

```
all_li = $('ul#nitsmenu > li');
$("#nitspopupmenu").sortable({
  start: function(event, ui) {
    startPos = ui.item.index();
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    newPos = ui.item.index();
    console.log("startposition: " + startPos);
    console.log("startposition: " + newPos);
    all_li.sort(function(startPos, newPos) {
      return $(startPos).data('menusort') - $(newPos).data('menusort');
    });
    $('#nitsmenu').append(all_li);
  }
});
```

`all_li` in the above code is `all_li = $('ul#nitsmenu > li');` 
link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzzf5yku/)

I'm getting index position properly. Please help

Comment: please, create a jsfiddle!

Comment: all_li is not defined

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/1yymfa1o/

Comment: check my last statement its defined... FYI [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzzf5yku/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/ejhLj7ep/

With 8 elements: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/810r5sgh/!

1. add id with number same li elements data-menusort.
2. use sortable to array in the div
3. get id and positions, so set attr data-menusort in the li elements

with firebug inspect code and see that data-menusort change!

furute: you can use refresh sort to order elements in ul

Html:

```
<div class="form-body ui-sortable" id="nitspopupmenu">
  <div id ="1" class="form-group ui-sortable-handle">
   <div class="pagesmenu selected"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Home
     </span>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div id ="2" class="form-group ui-sortable-handle">
   <div class="pagesmenu selected"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> About Us
    </span>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nitsmenu" data-nitspagelabel="1">
  <li id="li-1" class="scroll active" data-menusort="1"><a href="#navigation">Home</a></li>
  <li id="li-2" class="scroll" data-menusort="2"><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
$("#nitsmenu").sortable({});

$("#nitspopupmenu").sortable({
      stop: function (event, ui) {
        sortedIDs = $( "#nitspopupmenu" ).sortable( "toArray" );
        $.each(sortedIDs, function( index, value ) {
            liid = "li-"+value;
            pos = index + 1;
            $("#"+liid).attr("data-menusort",pos);
        });
        console.log(sortedIDs);
        reorder(sortedIDs);
    }
});

function reorder(orderedArray) {
    var el, pre, p = document.getElementById("li-"+orderedArray[0]).parentNode;
    orderedArray.forEach(function (a, b, c) {
        if (b > 0) {
            el = document.getElementById("li-"+a);
            pre = document.getElementById("li-"+c[b - 1]);
            p.insertBefore(el, pre.nextSibling);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update but li items are not re-positioning.

Comment: yes, but this code set positions, is not easy resolve all problem in two minutes -_-

Comment: Sorry bro, I didn't read the refresh thing you wrote about. Thanks for the help and patience..:)

Comment: @NitishKumar check new code! i add a new function to reorder the ul list!  work! Add vote and check this option resolve problem to close the thread!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can see its working on JSFiddle but while integrating it I'm getting an error of `Uncaught type error, Cannot read the property of parentNode of null`, even the values of data-menusort are not changing. Can you help me. Sorry for bothering you too much. I'm calling div dynamically as asked by you i inserted div ids too, I can see its been added appropriate.

Comment: at `console.log(sortedIDS);` I'm getting like this `["2", "1", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]`

Comment: add jsfiddle with new elements

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/810r5sgh/ In this example the code works fine with 8 elements.. sortedIDS get de id of elements sort.

Comment: @NitishKumar check id the divs and li.. if in div has id=1 in the list you need have id=li-1..

Comment: @Cuchu - consider scoping your variables: `iid =` as `var  liid =` etc.

Comment: div problem solved, but uncaught type error is from reorder function.

Comment: yes, the error has in reorder function because surely your set bad the id in the li. chekc with 8 options https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/810r5sgh/

Comment: @Cuchu I'm adding div dynamically, once I add the code I get an error, if I've codes written in html it doesn't throws error. Please see following [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/uhLynfyz/2/) which is not displaying the desired result

Comment: Your code work fine.. I uncomment reorder function and work fine.. In chrome. the Console not show errors.